# C# - Get Response from WebRequest and handle status codes

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing an updatesystem for .NET-applications and at the moment I am stuck. I try to get a file on a remote server and its content. For that I want to use a HttpWebRequest to get the content and the status code if the operation fails.

I built a function that contains a switch-query and each part asks the status code and does an action then.

This looks like the following:

```
public void AskStatusCode(int code)
{
  switch (code)
  {
  case 404:
     // Do an action
     break;

  case 405:
     // Do an action
     break;
  }
}
```

Ok, that is it. Now I created a HttpWebRequest and a HttpWebResponse.

```
HttpWebRequest requestChangelog = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
requestChangelog.Method = "GET";

HttpWebResponse changelogResponse = (HttpWebResponse)requestChangelog.GetResponse();

// Now call the function and set the status code of the response as parameter.
AskStatusCode((int)changelogResponse.StatusCode);
```

So, the theory should work, but it does not. It will not do any actions I put in the "case"-block for a special status code.

I removed the file from the remote server to test if it will execute the case-block for code **"404"**, but it always shows me an exception (remote server answered 404), but not that what I wanted this status code to handle with.

So, my question is, why is this not working? The types are integers and I casted the status code to an Int32 as well, as you could see...

To your info: After the status code had been checked and if it is ok, I want to read the content with a stream reader and the ResponseStream.

Help would be appreciated.
Excuse me, if you did not understand that, I tried to say it as clear as I could.

Comment: Can you enter the debugger and see what the value of changelogResponse.StatusCode is?

Comment: The problem is that I am testing it all on another PC because on mine I do not have internet at the moment, so I tried to show the result in a MessageBox. This MessageBox is never shown, that means the exception already comes up when I try to create the HttpWebRequest.
What should I do to get rid of that problem? A try-block seems not a good way to do this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to check whether the response failed because of a server error (the WebException provides a WebResponse) or not.
Maybe this will help you:

```
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/thisisadeadlink");
            request.Method = "GET";

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            Console.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
                Console.Write("Errorcode: {0}", (int)response.StatusCode);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Error: {0}", e.Status);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It worked out for me, the `response.StatusCode` must be checked after throwing an exception, not before, like OP's code

Answer (score 6):

StatusCodes in the range of 4xx and 5xx throw a `WebException` which is why the code is never reaching the switch statement.

You need to handle this exception in your code:

```
HttpWebRequest requestChangelog = null;
HttpWebResponse changelogResponse = null;

try
{
    requestChangelog = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    requestChangelog.Method = "GET";

    changelogResponse = (HttpWebResponse)requestChangelog.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    //handle the error
}

AskStatusCode((int)changelogResponse.StatusCode);
```

If you are only interested in checking error status codes then you would move the `AskStatusCode()` call inside of the catch block.

Comment: Ok, so a try-block seems to help. I just found out what you said, but I was not sure how to catch the problem and if a try-block would be useful. I will try it and comment if it solved. Thanks!

Comment: @DGibbs,Why not call the `AskStatusCode` method in catch block. I think that's what OP trying to do.

Comment: @Rahul What if the status code returned is a `200 OK`? Then `AskStatusCode` will never be called. I am assuming he wants to call it for all statuscodes and not just ones which throw an error.

Comment: Ok, so I tested it. That the try-block works was clear... And how do I get the status code from the response then? I mean in the catch block, because I created the response in the try-part.

Comment: @Rahul Exactly.... If the status code is a `200 OK`, then the catch is never entered and `AskStatusCode` is never called (assuming it is moved to the catch block as you propose). If he needs to call `AskStatusCode` for non-error types, then it cannot be inside the `catch` block.

Comment: @DominicTrade See the edit, you need to initialize the Request/Response outside of the block to ensure the correct scope

Comment: Right, but I think OP wants to do some action on failure and read the content on success. So I suggested that. As in his post he says `To your info: After the status code had been checked and if it is ok, I want to read the content with a stream reader and the ResponseStream.`+1 good answer.

Comment: @DGibbs Ah great, I am a bit confused because I am dealing with that problem since hours now. :D I will try it out, thanks very much.

Comment: @DGibbs I do not know what the problem is, but Visual Studio tells me: "Because of security restrictions, HttpWebRequest cannot be accessed."
Same with the Response. I declared it outside the block and keywords like "public" are not valid. Why is this giving me that error?

Code:
HttpWebRequest requestChangelog = new HttpWebRequest();

Comment: Try initialising the request/response to `null` instead of a new instance of each respective class

Comment: Thanks, that killed the errors, but I needed to solve this in an other way. I had no instance, so I could not ask for the status code with the response itself. I needed to cast the Status of the WebException.